# Neo4j return calculated field in query for geographical distance

Tags: neo4j

I started working few weeks ago with Neo4j and all I want to do is return all the nodes in the database (which all contain a property with their location in longitude/latitude format) ordered by the distance from a certain geographical point, specifically my current location.

This is the calculation needed:

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2 
c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) ) 
d = R * c (where R is the radius of the Earth)
```

I've read the documentation and I can't find how to store procedures to execute it as I'd do in other RDBMS, and I'm pretty sure I cannot perform a SIN or COS operation within the query.

Is there any way to execute this query against the database and get the ordered data rather than getting all the results and make the math one by one and return them manually ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher has a `haversin` function to calculate distances on the surface of a shere, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-mathematical.html#functions-haversin